# NSNumber and float - type casting oddity

Tags: objective-c, casting, floating-point, nsnumber

In my application I am using an external API which communicates using json. Today  I encountered strange (it may be strange just due to my inexperience in iOS) behavior between floats and NSNumbers. The thing is that I am receiving a float in APIs response, in this particular case it is 135.99. When native obj-c json parser parse the response it creates NSNumber with that value. It works perfect. But at when I started using this API I didn't know  how native json parser bahaves, so I've been doing something like this:

```
NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[response objectForKey:@"Number"] floatValue]];
```

So, what is happening above is actually casting NSNumber to float and creating new NSNumber with that float. And what is so strange about it? Strange (for me) is that above line generates NSNumber with value... 135.99001 instead of 135.99 which is the proper one.

I know that float arithmetics is really messed up, especially in languages like PHP (0.2 + 0.7 not equals 0.9), but I haven't expected that in languages like objective-c, which is a superset od C language, I would find such mess to. Does anyone has a good explanation to that issue?

Comment: _So, what is happening above is actually casting NSNumber to float and creating new NSNumber with that float._ why?

Comment: What happens if you "fix" the code by avoiding the conversion altogether: `NSNumber * number = [response objectForKey:@"Number"]`?

Comment: It works fine, but I made mistake which is mentioned above, I've figured it out. My question was why there are two different values (135.99 and 135.99001) when there should be one and the same in both cases (135.99), not how to fix it because I already know that.

Comment: OK what happens if you use `double` instead of `float`  (`numberWithDouble` and `doubleValue`)?

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not, in general, *really messed up*.  The evidence on SO is that many people have a *really messed up* understanding of the nature, subtleties and pitfalls of f-p arithmetic.

Comment: Ok, it is not messed up, but came to objective-c from php and there is  lot of things about real programming I still have to learn ;). @HighPerformanceMark I see your point and I totally agree.

Comment: You can test the hypothesis of `float` being imprecise yourself by assigning `float x = 135.99;`. I agree with @HighPerformanceMark. The behavior of `floats` is actually quite defined.

Answer (score 2):

You are making one beginners mistake, and that is assuming that "float" is the correct type for floating point numbers. It's not. Unless you have a really good reason to use float, "double" is the type that you should be using. JSON parsers will inevitably use [NSNumber numberWithDouble:...] to create the NSNumber objects they store (or [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:...] or NSDecimalNumber), but *never* [NSNumber numberWithFloat:].

float has very limited precision compared to double. You can be sure that in most cases, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:...] will give you different results because of the limited precision.

Answer (score 0):

For languages like C (and I suspect PHP, too) float (and double) arithmetics are not really tied to the language, but to the underlying hardware.

For modern computers that means IEEE floating point arithmetic as implemented by the CPU, so you'd get the same problems if you wrote your program in C, Pascal, FORTRAN, etc. They all just call the CPU's floating point instructions and leave it at that.

Answer (score -1):

Odd things happen with floats. It is part of their nature that they are inprecize.

Besides that I do not fully understand why you are converting (not just type casting) your nice NSNumber into float just to create a new NSNumber object out of the float, you should never ever expect two float values to be equal even if you cannot think of any reason why they should be different. 
Which means, when ever it comes to comparing floats, you should never ever compare `float1 == float2`. Better compare `abs(float1-float2) < 0.001` or what ever significance is of importance.

Some general about these behaviour of floats are well explained on this site: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: A I said in previous comments it was mistake bacause I didn't know that json parser creates NSNumber for me. I don't do that anymore. I was just curious why the value changed after convertion. Thank you for your answer, I'll check the website.

Comment: I figured this webside provides good explanation of the issue and gives good guidens how to deal with this. The issue is more general to the data type float and floating point operations in CPUs. It is not at all limited to Objective-C nor ARM processors.